# Movement Script in Godot lagging out scene unless jumping

Tags: godot, gdscript

My movement script for a game im working on heavily lags the game unless i jump, its smooth when jumping but extremely choppy when on the ground. The scene is really basic with just the player which is a capsule and the ground which is just a cube with collision. I do not know why it happens because im new to GDscript.

Here's the code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D


const SPEED = 5.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5


var gravity: float = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")
@onready var neck := $Neck
@onready var camera := $Neck/Camera3D

func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
    elif event.is_action_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE)
    if Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
        if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
            neck.rotate_y(-event.relative.x * 0.01)
            camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * 0.01)
            camera.rotation.x = clamp(camera.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-30), deg_to_rad(60))


func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    

    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta


    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    
    var input_dir := Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "back")
    var direction = (neck.transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

I didnt try much as i have no idea where anything is wrong. Hoping to find an answer here.

Comment: Nothing suspicious at a glance. What does profiling say to be eating more time? I wonder if it is something about the colliders. You might want to try setting a new project with only the bare minimum, that might shed some light on the problem, and if it does not then you have something for https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: @theraot the profiler says: Frame time .554, physics frame time 16.6, process time fluctuates around 4.0 and below, physics time 66.3. Frame time lowers drastically when i jump.

Comment: Could try swapping out `move_and_slide` for `move_and_collide(velocity * delta)` to see if sliding is causing it. Or debug print the velocity to see if the values are sensible.

Comment: A related "mystery lag" I have encountered is attempting to use key binds that do not exist. Check that the spellings of "left" "right" "forward" and "back" in your project settings.